# Running certain Hadoop Jobs only on a chosen node and not in the others, managing the process with Oozie

Tags: workflow, hadoop, workflow-engine

Is that even possible? I've searched quite a bit and I'd say it's not possible, but I think it's so strange a so basilar functionality has not been foreseen.

If i have a cluster of 3 machine and 1 is relative to a part (Let's say an action i Oozie) of the bigger process, can't i say to Oozie to run that job only on node X and not in the other nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don not think you can enforce Oozie launcher mapper to run on a certain node.